# Why explicit test for an empty set does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

If empty `set()` is `False`, shouldn't the `if test == False` clause in the following code evaluate to `True`?

```
test = set() 

#  empty sets are false
if test == False:
    print("set is empty")
else:
    print("set NOT empty")

if not test:
    print("set is empty")
```

ouput:

```
set NOT empty
set is empty
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In simple terms, the equals operator `==` will perform an equality comparison between those two objects: A set and a boolean value will never be equal, so the result of the comparison is false. On the other hand, just checking `if obj` (or `if not obj`) will check the trueness of the object, something that can be evaluated for every object. In a way, this actually does a type conversion using `if bool(obj)`. And for empty sets, this is false.

In the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), both of these operations invoke different special method names. Comparing two objects using the equality operator will invoke [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) while calling `bool()` on an object will invoke [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__).

Answer (score 7):

The operator `==` will check the values of 2 object and in this case an empty `set()` and a False value have not a same value.

And since python evaluates any empty sequence as False and none empty sequences as True, if you want to check the validation of the `test` object you can simple use `if`:

```
if test:
  #do stuff
```

> [**Truth Value Testing**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth)
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - List item
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

Answer (score 3):

The key point here is, `False` is not the only value that is considered falsy. An empty set is also interpreted as false in the condition.

However, the explicit equality test `test == False` is not true because an empty set, as definition, is of type `set`, which is never equal to a boolean value 
`False`.

---

See [Boolean Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#booleans):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.